# How to split string of biographical info into different dictionaries using regex, in Python?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, split

Recently I got my hands on a research project that would greatly benefit from learning how to parse a string of biographical data on several individuals into a set of dictionaries for each individual.

The string contains break words and I was hoping to create keys off of the breakwords and separate dictionaries by line breaks. So here are two people I want to create two different dictionaries for within my data:

> Bankers = [ ' Bakstansky, Peter; Senior Vice President, Federal
>   Reserve Bank of New         York, in charge of public information
>   since 1976, when he joined the NY Fed as Vice  President. Senior
>   Officer in charge of die Office of Regional and Community Affairs,
>   Ombudsman for the Bank and Senior Administrative Officer for Executive
>   Group, m zero children Educ City College of New York (Bachelor of
>   Business Administration, 1961); University of Illinois, Graduate
>   School, and New York University, Graduate School of Business. 1962-6:
>   Business and financial writer, New York, on American Banker, New
>   York-World Telegram & Sun, Neia York Herald Tribune (banking editor
>   1964-6). 1966-74: Chase Manhattan Bank: Manager of Public Relations,
>   based in Paris, 1966-71; Manager of Chase's European Marketing and
>   Planning, based in Brussels, 1971-2; Vice President and Director of
>   Public Relations, 1972-4.1974-76: Bache & Co., Vice President and
>   Director of Corporate Communications. Barron, Patrick K.; First Vice
>   President and < Operating Officer of the Federal Reserve Bank o
>   Atlanta since February 1996. Member of the Fed" Reserve Systems
>   Conference of first Vice Preside Vice chairman of the bank's
>   management Con and of the Discount Committee, m three child Educ
>   University of Miami (Bachelor's degree in Management); Harvard
>   Business School (Prog Management Development); Stonier Graduate Sr of
>   Banking, Rutgers University. 1967: Joined Fed Reserve Bank of Atlanta
>   in computer operations 1971: transferred to Miami Branch; 1974:
>   Assist: President; 1987: Senior Vice President.1988: re1- Atlanta as
>   Head of Corporate Services. Member Executive Committee of the Georgia
>   Council on Igmic Education; former vice diairman of Greater
>   ji§?Charnber of Commerce and the President'sof the University of
>   Miami; in Atlanta, former ||Mte vice chairman for the United Way of
>   Atlanta feiSinber of Leadership Atlanta. Member of the Council on
>   Economic Education. Interest. ' ]

So for example, in this data I have two people - Peter Batanksy and Patrick K. Barron. I want to create a dictionary for each individual with these 4 keys: `bankerjobs`, `Number of children`, `Education`, and `nonbankerjobs`.

In this text there are already break words: "m" = number of children "Educ", and anything before "m" is bankerjobs and anything after the first "." after Educ is nonbankerjobs, and the keyword to break between individuals seems to be any amount of spaces after a "."  >1

How can I create a dictionary for each of these two individuals with these 4 keys using regular expressions on these break words?

specifically, what set of regex could help me create a dictionary for these two individuals with these 4 keys (built on the above specified break words)?

A pattern i am thinking would be something like this in perl:

```
pattern = [r'(m/[ '(.*);(.*)m(.*)Educ(.*)/)']
```

but i'm not sure..

I'm thinking the code would be similar to this but please correct it if im wrong:

```
my_banker_parser = re.compile(r'somefancyregex')

def nested_dict_from_text(text):
    m = re.search(my_banker_parser, text)
    if not m:
    raise ValueError
    d = m.groupdict()
    return { "centralbanker": d }

result = nested_dict_from_text(bankers)
print(result)
```

My hope is to take this code and run it through the rest of the biographies for all of individuals of interest.

Comment: I am not a python expert, but is there anything wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Im sur ethe code itself is a problem, any advice on this would help

Comment: This sounds like an issue of terribly malformed input, that should go through a whole lot of sanitizing before dealing with any regular expressions.

Comment: You are thinking of using the semicolon to pick out the name `Barron, Patrick K.;` but there are semicolons elsewhere too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using named groups will probably be less brittle, since it doesn't depend on the pieces of data being in the same order in each biography.  Something like this should work:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?P<foo>foo)|(?P<bar>bar)|(?P<baz>baz)')
>>> data = {}
>>> for match in regex.finditer('bar baz foo something'):
...     data.update((k, v) for k, v in match.groupdict().items() if v is not None)
... 
>>> data
{'baz': 'baz', 'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'}
```

Comment: thanks, but how could I apply this to multiple amounts of individuals in the string? so if I wanted to get baz, foo, and bar for each person - how would  I parse that out? should I just take each chunk of biography and run them separately and then append into a corpus?

Comment: Also i'm confused in your example as to which foo is the  group and which one is the element to look for.. would something like this work? regex = re.compile(r'(?P<m>cbankjob)|(?P<Edu> numberofchildren)|(?P<.>otherjob)').

Comment: It goes `(?P<name_of_group>what you want to match)`.  As for applying the regular expression to all the people in the text, if you can split the document on their names, do so.  They don't seem to be very well delineated within the text (ie it's hard to tell where one biography ends and another starts).

Comment: Once you've done that, something like this should work (untested): `r'^(?P<name>[^;]+); (?P<bankerjobs>.+) m (?P<numberofchildren>\w+) child(?:ren)? Educ (?P<education>[^.]+). (?P<job_details>.+)$'`  Order is important here, but the sections aren't as clearly delineated as I thought at first...

Comment: thanks! I will try your reex and let you know if it works out once I split on names!

Comment: I managed to split on names. What happened was i split earlier on blankspaces to turn it into a a string with no noticeable delimiter (as you mentioned). My list, once split on spaces (specifically split on "/n/n/n/n" between names) is then put into another layer in your code:import re
regex = re.compile(r'^(?P<name>[^;]+); (?P<bankerjobs>.+) m (?P<numberofchildren>\w+) child(?:ren)? Educ (?P<education>[^.]+). (?P<job_details>.+)$)
data2 = {}
for entry in data1:
    for match in regex.finditer(entry):
         data2.update((k, v) for k, v in match.groupdict().items() if v is not None)

Comment: The problem, however, is when I do this , it stops updating the dictionary at the FIRST person, it doesn't include the second individual.

Comment: OK, well if the there is a good delimiter between records `\n\n\n\n`, you can just use that in the regular expression.  If do split on the records, you need to run the regular expression on each of them.

Comment: More generally, I can't fix all your bugs for you, especially without access to the actual data you're using.  I've given you enough hints to get started.  SO is for solving specific problems you have, not writing the code for you.  If you can't solve problems this simple, then you probably need to learn more about programming before you continue.